# Fatal Error The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted SOLUTION

Tags: postgresql, fatal-error, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

HEY GUYS I tried everything i could to make it work and I somehow did!!!

I'm running a windows 7 64-bit system, but i'm sure it can work for anything else. These are the steps I did:

1. Delete pgadmin 4 folder which can be found in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgadmin 4 or where you downloaded the PSQL folder. (This is to install a new version and get rid of the version you have)
2. Click the link to install a new version, is version 5, it worked for me:
   https://pgadmin-archive.postgresql.org/pgadmin4/v5.7/windows/index.html
3. Download the exe file above, and go thru the steps.
4. After it's downloaded, make sure to go to 'Program Files', if you see pgAdmin 4 v5 folder next to the PostgreSQL folder, drop the pgadmin 4 v5 folder in the PostgreSQL Folder\14 and leave it there. EXAMPLE (C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14(version)\pgadmin4 v5 )
5. Click Windows + R and type in %APPDATA%, see if in the Roaming folder there is a 'pgadmin' and click on the folder.
6. DELETE everything found inside the folder but NOT the folder itself.
7. Go to windows bar where you can run the 'pgadmin4 v5': remember this is the newer version, so make sure you deleted the previous version just in case you don't get confused.
8. Right-click pgAdmin v5 and run as administrator, click yes, and then let it wait until it goes to the server.
9. If this doesn't work the first time don't worry, it took me a few times, but keep going to Windows + R and type %APPDATA%, go to Roaming\pgadmin and delete everything found inside the folder again, and then run the pgAdmin v5 as administrator again.

LET ME KNOW IF THIS WORKS. IF NOT I CAN HELP YOU WITH OTHER STEPS BUT THIS SHOULD WORK!!!!

Comment: Per [Downloads](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/): "pgAdmin is available for 64 bit Windows™ 7 SP1 (desktop) or 2008R2 (server) and above, up to v4.30. v5.0 and later are supported on Windows 8 (desktop) or 2012 (server) and above."